# node js application insight sampling, sample all but errors/exceptions

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Azure App insight module for Node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights) which have an option to set sample by *appInsights.defaultClient.config.samplingPercentage*.

By this all type of logs will be sampled like (traces, requests, exceptions etc.). Is there any way to sample all but exception (I want to post 100% exception to app insight).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT*: There are some changes to make the code to work

You can try it with [Telemetry Processors in node.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/#preprocess-data-with-telemetry-processors).

The sample code:

```
function samplingControl ( envelope, context ) {
  if (envelope.data.baseType === "ExceptionData") {
      //all exception data will be sent
      envelope.sampleRate = 100;
  }
  else
  {
     envelope.sampleRate = 33;
  }
  return true;
}

appInsights.defaultClient.addTelemetryProcessor(samplingControl);
```